# Basic Code for 3xbee's: 1 Coordinator & 2 routers

Tags: api, arduino, communication, router, xbee

I have been researching 3 way communication for xbee's. I have figured out the configuration for 1 coordinator and 2 routers. The Problem is that I cant seem to find a code to test this communication. All I need is a simple code for the coordinator to send  a different message to the routers at the same time. I am honestly stumped. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need the [XCTU](https://www.digi.com/products/xbee-rf-solutions/xctu-software/xctu) provided by Digi. Than if you want to send and receive data you can use this software.

If you want to write your own program I recommend using [xbee](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XBee). This python module has anything you need: Examples on how to read packets sent by the routers or end devices and examples on how to send remote commands from the coordinator to the remote devices or vice versa.

Example 1 - Read packets sent from the remote devices:

```
from xbee import ZigBee
import serial

PORT = '/dev/ttyAMA0' #change AMA0 to USB0 or another port if is necessary
BAUD_RATE = 9600 #the baudrate

# Open serial port
ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD_RATE)

# Create API object
xbee = ZigBee(ser)

# Continuously read and print packets
while True:
    try:
        response = xbee.wait_read_frame()
        print(response)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ser.colose()
        break
```

Example 2 - Send remote commands to the devices:

```
from xbee import ZigBee
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)
xbee = ZigBee(ser)

#send command to change Pin 4 of the Xbee to LOW
xbee.send('remote_at',
          frame_id='A',
          dest_addr_long='\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\x24\x20\x7D', #this is the serial address(like the MAC address) of the device. You can read it with XCTU(SH and SL parameters) or you can read it from the back of the device
          options='\x02',
          command='D4', #pin4
          parameter='\x04') #change status to low(\x05 for high status)

#send 1 packet/second with the status of the pins 
xbee.send('remote_at',
          frame_id='B',
          dest_addr_long='\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\x24\x20\x7D',
          options='\x02',
          command='IR', #sample rate parameter
          parameter='\x03\xE8') #1000 in hex

#write the above changes
xbee.send('remote_at',
          frame_id='C',
          dest_addr_long='\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\x24\x20\x7D',
          options='\x02',
          command='WR')
```

I hope this is helpful.